# Hibernate entities persistance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Imagine I get new entity from front-end. Java classes for that look like:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private Long id;

    private String nameOfSomeClass;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "someClass")
    private List<Other> others;

}
```

And:

```
public class Other {

    private Long id;

    private String otherName;        

    @ManyToOne
    private SomeClass someClass;

}
```

My POST request from front-end:

```
{
    nameOfSomeClass: "Some name"
    others: [{
            otherName: "name1"
        },
        {
            otherName: "name2"
        }

    ]
}
```

How can I persist this object? Actually I have no id of `Other` which has reference on `SomeClass`. The same case for the `SomeClass`.

My vision of that: firstly I need persist each element of `others` with empty `id` reference for the `SomeClass`. After that, I will get `id's` of each of `others`. Then I will persist `SomeClass` object and get `id` and persist `others` again but with `id` of `SomeClass`.

I know that is totally wrong and hibernate has some correct solution for that. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: If `name` is unique, use it as `ID`

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I use `id` as PK in database, name isn't unique

Answer (score 0):

The way you should hadle this is:

create an instance of `SomeClass` fill it with the values,
create the instaces of `Other` and fill them and add the end "link" them together:

```
SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
s.setNameOfSomeClass(nameOfSomeClass);

Other o1 = new Other();
o1.setOtherName(otherName);
o1.setSomeClass(s)

List others = new ArrayList();
others.add(o1);

s.setOthers(others);
```